# Passing struct by reference vs after malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc

What is the difference between these two approaches in terms of data visibility and memory overhead (any other differences would be great as well):

1. Passing a local struct by reference
2. Passing a pointer to the allocated memory

```
typedef struct student_data_t_ {
    char name[30];
    int score;
} student_data_t;

void fill_values (student_data_t *data) {
    snprintf(data->name, 30, "Howard");
    data->score = 20;
    return;
}

int main (void) {
    student_data_t record;
    student_data_t *ptr = NULL;

    fill_values(&record); // <1> passing the struct by reference

    ptr = (student_data_t *)malloc(sizeof(student_data_t));
    if (!ptr) {
        printf("NOMEM");
        return 0;
    }

    fill_values(ptr);  // <2> passing after allocating memory

    if (ptr) {
        free(ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a difference? It should be same, IMO.

Comment: I don't see any difference (other than what the variable contains).

Comment: are you sure that you understand what reference is and what is the difference with pointers?

Comment: BTW, there is no references in C, only in C++

Comment: One is allocated on the stack and one is allocated on the heap -- is this what you are after?

Comment: @Lashane what I am trying to understand is whether there is any advantage to using a malloc version over the local struct version. I understand C simulates pass-by-reference.

Comment: you don't free the malloced memory in this example.  **not a good idea**

Comment: @Hogan I saw that coming. fixed now. what happens if I store the address of this local struct `record` in a global pointer, and the function (main() here) returns, and I try to access the data using this pointer? is having a malloc version better in that case?

Comment: @adizone - yes for a global variable you need to malloc.

Comment: 1 and 2 are exactly the same method of passing . The real question  is "what is the difference between automatic variables and allocated variables" .   (sometimes called 'stack' and 'heap' in jargon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a local variable the memory overhead will exist entirely in the stack for that thread. If you use a large structure in say an embedded system, this can become a concern, as you risk a stack overflow. Generally you will use only the number of bytes requested, but stack space can be limited. (Some applications I work in have a stack of 512 bytes or less)

In the case of using malloc, you are allocating memory from the heap. This avoid the stack size concerns, but adds the requirement that you free the memory when you are done.

Visibility is determined by the variable you store the pointer in.

It is very dangerous to pass a local variable to a seperate thread, and can lead to undefined behavior if the local variable becomes invalid, say due to the function returning.

Comment: About whether you need to free memory when the program is ending. The answer is yes you really should. While more robust operating systems will track what memory belongs to each process, and free it automatically at the end, not all operating systems will do this. It is good practice to clean up your own mess.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of visibility, as long as the function does NOT return, will the local address `&record` be valid everywhere in the program? And, is  the malloc version the right way in case the function returns?

Comment: If you are using multiple threads, i highly suggest using malloc, and when cleaning up the thread freeing the memory.

Comment: As far as visibility of the stack, if it is in the same process you shouldn't have any problems as long as the function does not return. You can take advantage of this with an idle loop as an example, spinning off all of your threads, then looping with the information each thread uses inside of the stack of the idle thread. As long as the idle loop joins the threads before you return from it you should be alright. The key is to ensure that nothing and I mean NOTHING is using that data when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a local structure is bound to be faster, the program can do groovey things at compilation time. From a machine code point of view, a local structure is effectively a constant memory address.
When you start to use malloc there is bound to be a processing overhead, there is also a space issue. Although both structures are the same malloc will probably "use" more memory than sizeof(struct) just to store the data. malloc also reserves space on every page to maintain and memory address size allocated memory lookup table, this allows free to only need an address as paramaters.

One of the biggest issues is development time introduction malloc and free to programs increases the chance of bugs, especially segmentation faults. Without mentioning the hard to track down "invisible " bug of a memory leak. 
But using malloc and calloc is the only way to deal with user input, you never know how much data they're gonna enter, a text input buffer of say 2kb can easily over fill with a call to fgets